# Is this example of "en" ending noun that I found in a book really true?

Tags: grammatical-case, grammatical-number

I can't understand according to which rule such nouns have been declined in this example:

> 1- An vielen kleinen Haltestellen gibt es nur einen Fahrkartenautomaten.

I can't exactly comprehend why we have : "Fahrkartenautomaten" with 'en' ending! It's  not accusative, because we only change article and adjective in Accusative case. It's doesn't seem plural, because before that it says: "einen". It doesn't look  genitive because there aren't two nouns. And definitely it's not Dative, because in Dative only plural nouns have "en" ending.

Comment: I can't really understand what has happened in the sentence, please someone explain.

Comment: You should brush up a bit on your German grammar knowledge. It is accusative. Your explanation why it can't be is wrong.

Comment: But it is in Akkusativ. A [declension table](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Automat) can tell you that. Note: it should be an vielen *kleinen* not kleine.

Comment: Your only problem is to identify the accusative here. Here is a simple method: with *es gibt* you may ask: *Es gibt **wen oder was?*** Ergo accusative.

Comment: Follow-up question: Why does Fahrkartenautomat have an -en- in the middle? We say Apfelbaum, not *Aepfelbaum. Why do we say Fahrkartenautomat and not *Fahrkarteautomat?

Comment: Technically you are right. Akkusative can also be without "-en" here, like: gibt es nur einen Fahrkartenautomat.

Comment: @mic Please don't tell learners, that *gibt es nur einen Fahrkartenautomat* would be correct! It's not. The *-en* ist not optional. See also [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/56181/n-deklination-stirbt-aus).

Comment: @Olafant - well, there seem to be different opinions about it (also in the cited article). But I could agree that it is not yet an officially accepted ending.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It *is* an accusative. The sentence translates as *At many small stops there is only one* (or: *a*) *ticket machine.* The English *there is* in German is realised as *es gibt*, and *es gibt* is followed by an accusative object (question: *Wen/Was gibt es?*):

> *Es gibt [ein großes Problem]<sub>Akk.</sub> / [zehn Autos]<sub>Akk.</sub> / [schwierige Fragen]<sub>Akk.</sub> / [einen
>   Fahrkartenautomaten]<sub>Akk.</sub>*

(As you can verify using [Canoo](http://www.canoonet.eu/inflection/automat:N:M), *Fahrkartenautomaten* is indeed the accusative singular of *Fahrkartenautomat*.)

You may find some helpful context at https://www.dartmouth.edu/~deutsch/Grammatik/Nouns/accusative.html.

Comment: First of all, Thanks. I got that there are some weak nouns. So, is "Automat" also a weak noun?! I didn't find it in the list of the link you have given.

Comment: Oh hopefully I found a comprehensive explanation about weak nouns and a list of them here: https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/10973844/German-s-Weak-Nouns-Explanation

Comment: Yes. (Though it looks like you've already figured that out by yourself.)

Comment: Thanks dear @johnl but seriously I didn't know it before asking the question.

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest otherwise, I just didn't want to leave the question unanswered. :)

Comment: Yes, I found it out. Thanks a lot dear @johnl :)

Answer (score 3):

The word *Fahrkartenautomat* is a compound noun. The building blocks are:

- die Fahrkarte = ticket
- der Automat = automaton, machine

So the whole word means *ticket machine*. (The first part, *Fahrkarte* is again a compound noun, it is build from the verb *fahren* = to travel and the noun *die Karte* = card, giving *Fahrkarte* = traveling card, and *Fahrkartenautomat* = traveling card machine)

In a compound noun it is always the last part that rules the gender of the whole word, and it also rules the declination. So, *Fahrkartenautomat* is masculine, because *Automat* is masculine, and the declination of *Fahrkartenautomat* is exactly the same as of *Automat*:

**Singular:**

- Nominative

  > Dieser Kasten hier ist **der Fahrkartenautomat**.
  >   Dieser Kasten hier ist **der Automat**.
  >
  > This box here is the ticket machine.
  >   This box here is the  machine.
- Genitive

  > Die Reisenden bedienen sich **des Fahrkartenautomaten**.
  >   Die Reisenden bedienen sich **des Automaten**.
  >
  > The travelers make use of the ticket machine.
  >   The travelers make use of the machine.
- Dativ

  > Der Erste-Hilfe-Kasten ähnelt **dem Fahrkartenautomaten**.
  >   Der Erste-Hilfe-Kasten ähnelt **dem Automaten**.
  >
  > The first aid box is similar to the ticket machine.
  >   The first aid box is similar to the machine.
- Akkusativ

  > Ich sehe **den Fahrkartenautomaten**.
  >   Ich sehe **den Automaten**.
  >
  > I see the ticket machine.
  >   I see the machine.

**Plural:**

- Nominative

  > Diese Kästen hier sind **die Fahrkartenautomaten**.
  >   Diese Kästen hier sind **die Automaten**.
  >
  > These boxes here are the ticket machines.
  >   These boxes here are the machines.
- Genitive

  > Die Reisenden bedienen sich **der Fahrkartenautomaten**.
  >   Die Reisenden bedienen sich **der Automaten**.
  >
  > The travelers makes use of the ticket machines.
  >   The travelers makes use of the machines.
- Dativ

  > Die Erste-Hilfe-Kästen ähneln **den Fahrkartenautomaten**.
  >   Die Erste-Hilfe-Kästen ähnelt **den Automaten**.
  >
  > The first aid boxes are similar to the ticket machines.
  >   The first aid boxes are similar to the machines.
- Akkusativ

  > Ich sehe **die Fahrkartenautomaten**.
  >   Ich sehe **die Automaten**.
  >
  > I see the ticket machines.
  >   I see the machines.

The Verb *etwas geben* (to be something) needs its Object in accusative case:

> Es gibt **einen Fahrkartenautomaten.**
>   Es gibt **einen Automaten.**
>
> There is a ticket machine.
>   There is a machine.

Comment: Thanks for your complete description dear @Hubert Schölnast . Now I understand that this change also occurs for other cases except nominative. And if in a dictionary we find a masculine noun with "es" sign to add for example: der Gott, that would only occur for Genitive and no more on Dative or Accusative. Am I right?

Comment: That is correct but your dictionary should also tell you so.

Comment: Thanks @infinitezero, Do you mean for those weak nouns that have a separate from only common in Dative and Accusative and another form for Genitive? E.g. in my Langenscheidt and Oxford dictionary after the weak noun "Name" it's been written: "ns" postfix. So we would have "Namen" for D and A and "Namens" for G?

Comment: [Declension table for Name](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Name)

Answer (score 0):

It's called N-ceclension. Der Automat is one of those n-declension words. (often words imported from a foreign language.

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Could you please add some more information about your mentioned rules and regulatories, maybe some examples or links for further understanding?