# n-Deklination stirbt aus?

Tags: grammaticality

Hier (ganz unten) https://deutschegrammatik20.de/das-substantiv-nomen/n-deklination/ steht Folgendes:

> Die n-Deklination ist eine absterbende Sprachform. Die Endungen im
>   Singular werden heute in der gesprochenen Sprache meist weggelassen.

Liebe Muttersprachler, ist es wirklich so? Bedeutet das, dass jedes Mal wenn ich sagte *ich kenne einen Brite**n*** oder *ich danke Ihnen von Herz**en***, habe ich grammatikalisch (für die Umgangssprache) falsche Sätze gebildet?

Comment: Nö. War alles richtig. Die Behauptung, dass es ausstürbe, nehme ich mir nicht zu Herzen. Denn mein Gebrauch lebt noch, was nach mit kommt kommt nach mir. Würde ein fehlendes n wie auf der Seite notiert auch als "kann keine Fälle deklinieren" verstehen.

Comment: Ist eher umgekehrt: in den Dialekten gibt es die oft nicht aber die Dialekte sterben (in weiten Teilen von D) aus.  Also netto Zuwachs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> > Die n-Deklination ist eine absterbende Sprachform.

Ich halte das für ein Gerücht (nach dem Motto: früher war alles besser). Schon zu meiner Grundschulzeit vor fast 40 Jahren habe ich mich oft gewundert, warum manche Leute mit dem Wort *jemand* Schwierigkeiten haben. (Da fiel mir das besonders auf.) Und das ist bis heute so geblieben.

> > Bedeutet das, dass jedes Mal wenn ich sagte *ich kenne einen Briten* oder *ich danke Ihnen von Herzen*, habe ich grammatikalisch (für die Umgangssprache) falsche Sätze gebildet?

Nein. Das bedeutet es eben nicht. Die Sätze sind völlig korrekt. An dieser Frage sieht man sehr gut die Macht der selbsterfüllenden Prophezeihung. Wenn Seiten, die sich *deutschegrammatik* nennen, Fehler als moderne Entwicklung propagieren, halten die Leute solche Fehler vielleicht irgendwann tatsächlich für völlig normal.

Was sich tatsächlich geändert hat, ist die sprachliche Kompetenz der Journalisten. Man suche nur mal auf tagesschau.de nach einem fehlerfreien Artikel. Vielleicht ist es auch nur mangelnde Sorgfalt aus zeitlichem Druck. Außerdem werden dank Internet heute sehr viel mehr Texte unprofessioneller Autoren gelesen und gehõrt. Das größte Sendungsbewusstsein haben aber nicht unbedingt die Leute mit der größten sprachlichen Kompetenz. Das alles kann sich aber auch wieder ändern. Möglicherweise werten schon die Kinder der Millennials Facebook und Youtube als vollkommen veralteten Schwachsinn.

In der Metro in Tokio sieht man heute recht viele Leute aller Altersstufen Bücher lesen. Vielleicht werden Bücher in nicht allzu ferner Zukunft das neue [Tamagotchi](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamagotchi). ;)

Comment: Schade, dass ich nur einmal upvoten kann. Den vorletzten Absatz von *Was sich tatsächlich geändert hat* bis *mit der größten sprachlichen Kompetenz.* sollte sich jeder **fett** ausdrucken, einrahmen und an die Wand hängen!

Comment: Es wollten halt irgendwann alle *was mit Medien machen*. Auch die, die besser Taxifahrer geworden wären. Für viele wird auch das zur selbsterfüllenden Prophezeiung.

Comment: Muttersprachler machen per Definition keine *Fehlern*. Du willst hier effektiv behaupten, andere Menschen würden die falsche Sprache sprechen. Natürlich wirst du erwidern, das sei Nonsens, würdest mir damit aber implizit recht geben. Also spar es dir.

Comment: @vectory Ein Muttersprachler, der beispielsweise den Unterschied zwischen *ich gehe ins Bett* und *ich gehe im Bett* nicht versteht, beherrscht seine [Muttersprache](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Muttersprache) nicht. Er spricht dann nicht *die falsche Sprache*, er spricht nur *die Sprache falsch*. Dein erster Satz führt übrigens deine Behauptung ad absurdum.

Answer (score 10):

Es liegt im Wesen des Aussterbens, dass es langsam geschieht. Der Prozess ist eindeutig im Gang, aber ebenso eindeutig noch nicht einmal halb abgelaufen.

"Einen Briten" oder "einen Studenten" (wie verlinkt) kennt man auch heute noch. Akut bedroht sind dagegen Endungen wie "einem Eisbär*en* begegnen" oder "den Präsident*en* kritisieren". Ob die Veränderung auf alle Formen aller Worte der n-Deklination übergreifen wird, ist nicht sicher, aber möglich.

Comment: Meiner Meinung nach sind auch "einem Eisbären beim Aussterben zusehen" oder das mit "dem Präsidenten" noch absolut gängig - wohlgemerkt in der gesprochenen Umgangssprache.